# DirectX - Pixel Shader 3.0 doesn't work

Tags: c#, directx, shader

I’ve been working on a 3D project for quite some time now, to display model files from a engine. I wrote it in C# and using the Managed DirectX wrapper (I know it is old and deprecated, but I have my own reasons to use it). I needed to write a Pixel Shader to do texture blending and lighting, but ps 2.0 was too limited for my shader, and I needed to use ps 3.0. It works fine on with software rendering (DeviceType set to Reference), and on Hardware with ps 2.0 it works fine too, but when I use Hardware acceleration, the pixel shader just stops working. Doing some research, I discovered that my GPU (Intel GMA 950) only supports up to ps 2.0, okay that must be the issue. The problem is that, I asked some friends to test my app, and they all got the same problem (one of them even have a Geforce GTX650 that was supposed to support SM 5.0). The Pixel Shader doesnt do anything, and the model just remains at the vertex color.

Is there something special needed to make Pixel Shader work in Hardware?

Comment: Try a PIX capture.  Also, is this some sort of legacy test? The GMA950 card sucked when it came out, more than 10 years ago!  :)

Comment: Hah, no. My video card stopped working and I have old hardware - a Pentium Dual Core processor. Ill try the PIX Capture.

Comment: Do you get any HRESULT errors or output from the Direct3D DEBUG layer?--assuming you are on an equally old OS as Direct3D 9 debugging is not supported on Windows 8 or later.

Comment: Well, I managed to get some output from Direct3D with DebugView, the only message related to shader I got was "[5332] D3DX: ID3DXEffect: Warning! Failed to create shader on this device (probably because shader version is unsupported)". It is probably expected through, the problem is that the Pixel Shader doesnt work even on computers with powerful video card capable of Shader Model 5.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem reinstalling the SDK and changing the Microsoft.Direct3DX.dll to 1.0.2911.0 (April 2006) version, now it works fine with ps 3.0 on capable video cards. Thanks to all you guys.

Comment: Keep in mind that Managed DirectX 1.1 has been deprecated for ages, and April 2006 is the last version. See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx). You should consider moving to something newer like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/).